# SSRS Tablix Row Height When Printed

Tags: reporting-services, printing

Hopefully I am overlooking a something simple.

I have tablix control with a table row in it.  I have it set to can grow as is necessary, it works great.   The only problem I have is that when the row grows, when printed, the entire table contents matches the row height of the row that grew.   So single spaced lines now appear to be double-spaced which is unnecessary for this report.   We want to keep it as small as possible.   Sure we can tinker with the spacing of the fields in the row but the minute we get data that is a character too big, that will end the reports usefullness.

Let me know if there is something I can do.  Either setting or code wise.   Again, on screen it appears fine, but when printed the rows grow to match regardless of any settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by making placeholders for fields and enabling the HTML - Interpret Tags as styles option for each item in the tablix's detail row.

From [Placeholders for SSRS Expressions](http://www.bengribaudo.com/blog/2012/06/27/2039/placeholders-for-ssrs-expressions):

> To get started using placeholders, click inside a text box as though
>   you were going to edit the box’s text, then right-click and choose
>   Create Placeholder.

Comment: Man, this helped me out so much. Was beating my head against the wall over this.